# Flexbox en column y sticky-menu

Tags: flexbox

Tengo un header con flexbox en column para que debajo esté el menú. Mi pretensión es tenerlo en columna con dos elementos y hacer que el **menú tenga la misma anchura que la foto.**.
Con el código que tengo para hacer sticky el menú en top:0 no me funciona. He probado con muchas versiones ya y estoy sin salida. Es más, no sé si tiene salida este asunto. Lo veo negro. Gracias de antemano si tú lo ves mejor.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos.
Caminante.

```css
header { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: transparent; 
 }

.fotomenu {
 border: 2px solid violet;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {border: 2px solid salmon;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
margin-top: 0;
}


.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css"/>
 
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <!-- /header -->
 <header>
       <div class="fotomenu">
         <img border=1px src="img/aaacamino02jpg" width="" height="">
       
         <nav class="sticky">
       <a href="#">Inicio</a>
       <a href="#">Presentación</a>
       <a href="#">Formación</a>
       <a href="#">Presencias</a>
       <a href="#">Calendario</a>
       <a href="#">Dirección</a>
         </nav>
       </div>
 </header>
 
 <main class="presenta centrac">
 
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae tincidunt arcu. Etiam elit nibh, venenatis et ultricies in,
 porta a augue. Morbi vel sem at ex congue cursus et ac ante. In hac
 habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam vitae sagittis nulla. Suspendisse
 sed ultricies orci, vel ornare lectus. Integer id orci imperdiet,
 pulvinar elit malesuada, faucibus neque. Vestibulum ornare eros sit
 amet turpis blandit condimentum at eget leo. Nunc eu sagittis eros.
 Etiam eget turpis dapibus, pellentesque velit sit amet, efficitur
 libero. Etiam porttitor ullamcorper mauris, ut elementum est malesuada
 ut. Cras volutpat mauris pharetra diam rhoncus, quis tincidunt augue
 vulputate. Morbi scelerisque posuere nibh ac faucibus. Aliquam
 vulputate ac elit in mollis.
 In pretium diam quis enim tempus auctor. Vestibulum consectetur ut magna a porta. Ut ornare interdum maximus. Suspendisse potenti. Donec
 tempus molestie diam, sit amet maximus ipsum molestie a. Aenean
 condimentum sollicitudin cursus. Sed pretium massa vitae arcu gravida
 vehicula. Quisque tristique eu purus ut vestibulum. Suspendisse
 finibus diam ac ex pulvinar, id rhoncus erat efficitur. Nulla pulvinar
 tortor orci, id posuere turpis pretium sed. Nulla viverra viverra
 lorem, id interdum nunc auctor sed. Donec aliquam, velit non suscipit
 euismod, nunc est commodo mi, id tincidunt orci diam vitae erat.
 
 Mauris augue mi, feugiat a sapien eget, venenatis ultricies ante. Nulla facilisi. Sed eu lacus enim. Aliquam et metus at felis cursus
 ultricies a vitae odio. Pellentesque a sodales dui, id pellentesque
 lorem. Sed at efficitur nibh, dapibus porttitor mi. Suspendisse
 aliquam dolor et mauris ornare, at volutpat dui ultrices. Duis dapibus
 in purus in tincidunt. Aenean sit amet quam mollis, malesuada enim a,
 dignissim sapien. Donec pulvinar pretium odio. Quisque quis enim
 imperdiet, malesuada augue sit amet, pellentesque purus. Nam luctus
 lectus eget leo dictum ullamcorper. Nam euismod mattis ante.
 
 Sed a sapien odio. Donec ac lectus pulvinar, consequat justo vel, fermentum augue. Ut eget neque sapien. Ut quis mollis sapien. Aenean
 sed aliquet nibh, nec finibus ligula. Curabitur ligula velit, dictum
 eu feugiat ac, egestas tempor augue. Vestibulum quis commodo lacus, ac
 tempus nisl. Duis sit amet porttitor justo.
 
 Integer posuere leo et est scelerisque, at rhoncus orci mattis. Phasellus et metus at est accumsan blandit eget eget mauris.
 Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
 posuere cubilia Curae; In interdum eu risus nec ullamcorper. Integer
 facilisis tortor sit amet magna mattis ullamcorper. Mauris quis massa
 sit amet sem interdum aliquet. Fusce sed arcu sit amet quam ultrices
 accumsan. Quisque id diam id metus condimentum tincidunt.Lorem ipsum
 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae tincidunt
 arcu. Etiam elit nibh, venenatis et ultricies in, porta a augue. Morbi
 vel sem at ex congue cursus et ac ante. In hac habitasse platea
 dictumst. Nullam vitae sagittis nulla. Suspendisse sed ultricies orci,
 vel ornare lectus. Integer id orci imperdiet, pulvinar elit malesuada,
 faucibus neque. Vestibulum ornare eros sit amet turpis blandit
 condimentum at eget leo. Nunc eu sagittis eros. Etiam eget turpis
 dapibus, pellentesque velit sit amet, efficitur libero. Etiam
 porttitor ullamcorper mauris, ut elementum est malesuada ut. Cras
 volutpat mauris pharetra diam rhoncus, quis tincidunt augue vulputate.
 Morbi scelerisque posuere nibh ac faucibus. Aliquam vulputate ac elit
 in mollis.
 

 Mauris augue mi, feugiat a sapien eget, venenatis ultricies ante. Nulla facilisi. Sed eu lacus enim. Aliquam et metus at felis cursus
 ultricies a vitae odio. Pellentesque a sodales dui, id pellentesque
 lorem. Sed at efficitur nibh, dapibus porttitor mi. Suspendisse
 aliquam dolor et mauris ornare, at volutpat dui ultrices. Duis dapibus
 in purus in tincidunt. Aenean sit amet quam mollis, malesuada enim a,
 dignissim sapien. Donec pulvinar pretium odio. Quisque quis enim
 imperdiet, malesuada augue sit amet, pellentesque purus. Nam luctus
 lectus eget leo dictum ullamcorper. Nam euismod mattis ante.
 
 Sed a sapien odio. Donec ac lectus pulvinar, consequat justo vel, fermentum augue. Ut eget neque sapien. Ut quis mollis sapien. Aenean
 sed aliquet nibh, nec finibus ligula. Curabitur ligula velit, dictum
 eu feugiat ac, egestas tempor augue. Vestibulum quis commodo lacus, ac
 tempus nisl. Duis sit amet porttitor justo.
 
 Integer posuere leo et est scelerisque, at rhoncus orci mattis. Phasellus et metus at est accumsan blandit eget eget mauris.
 Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
 posuere cubilia Curae; In interdum eu risus nec ullamcorper. Integer
 facilisis tortor sit amet magna mattis ullamcorper. Mauris quis massa
 sit amet sem interdum aliquet. Fusce sed arcu sit amet quam ultrices
 accumsan. Quisque id diam id metus condimentum tincidunt.
 
 </main>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```